# Is there a way to quickly strip all but one UID (User ID) from a PGP public key?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, uid, stripping

I am attaching my PGP public key to the outgoing messages.
My key however has 10 User IDs, each corresponding to a different email.
I don't want the recipient to know all my **other** email addresses, so I want to strip them from the key before sending.

I am only aware of a very slow way for deleting the UIDs; **deleting one UID at the time**.
Is there a way to quickly produce a version of my public key with only one UID?